# Testing if array is heap

Tags: java, heap

This method tests an array of integers satisfies to see if its a max binary heap. This means

1. each node is greater than or equal to it's children
2. each node has at most 2 children
3. the leaf nodes are filled from left to right

This is for heaps that do not use element 0. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900388/why-in-a-heap-implemented-by-array-the-index-0-is-left-unused).

```
/*returns true if array satisfies heap property for heap from [START, END]*/  
private boolean isHeap(final int[] heap, final int START, final int END) {  
    for(int i = START; i <= Math.ceil(END / 2); i++) {  
       if(2 * i + 1 <= END && heap[i] < heap[2 * i + 1])  
               return false;  
       else if(2 * i <= END && heap[i] < heap[2 * i])  
               return false;  
   }  

   return true;  

}
```

Comment: What's broken about this?

Comment: @Pimgd nothing. I'm just asking if there's a better way to tell if something's a heap. I thought broken code is off topic on this site?

Comment: @Pimgd `heap` is not an array, it is declared as `final int heap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Possible bug

The method `isHeap` takes an array along with a start and end index. Although the code does try to take into account potential out of bounds by checking `2 * i + 1 <= end` and `2 * i <= end`, there is no check that `end` is strictly lower than `heap.length`. As such, out of bounds array indexes can still occur:

```
isHeapReview(new int[] { 0 }, 0, 1);
```

would throw an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`. There are multiple solutions depending on the intended usage of the method:

- You can defend from such a case by re-defining `end` to be the minimum of the given `end` and `heap.length - 1` with `Math.min(end, heap.length - 1)`.
- You can check if `end` is greater or equal than `heap.length` and, if true, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

In the same way, there is no check that `start` is a positive integer. Those checks should be added to it too.

#### Code style

Watch out your indentation style and braces. The following

> ```
> if(2 * i + 1 <= END && heap[i] < heap[2 * i + 1])  
>         return false;  
> else if(2 * i <= END && heap[i] < heap[2 * i])  
>         return false;
> ```

doesn't use curly braces and is not indented properly. Even if they are redundant, [it is best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java) to explicitely add the curly braces, as they prevent future possible issues. Use this style instead:

> ```
> if (2 * i + 1 <= end && heap[i] < heap[2 * i + 1]) {
>     return false;
> } else if (2 * i <= end && heap[i] < heap[2 * i]) {
>     return false;
> }
> ```

where the braces were added, indentation is fixed, spaces are added after `if`; all of this contribute to easier to read code.

#### Simplification

`end / 2` performs integer division and will return an integer, so invoking `Math.ceil` on it will have no effect. You can remove it; the code already loops from 0 to `end / 2` inclusive.

Also, since `end` is expected to be lower or equal than `heap.length - 1`, you can remove the `2 * i <= END` check in:

```
if (2 * i <= END && heap[i] < heap[2 * i])
```

This will always be true since `i` maximal value is `end / 2`.

With this change, you can even refactor the `if` statement to:

> ```
> if (2 * i + 1 <= END && heap[i] < heap[2 * i + 1] || heap[i] < heap[2 * i]) {
>     return false;
> }
> ```

without the need of an `else if` statement. It does make the line a tiny bit longer, but it is short enough to typically fit on a screen and is pretty direct.

#### Namings

Don't write the parameters in upper-case; only use this for constants. `START` should really be `start`; in the same way, `END` should be `end`.

Comment: Couple questions about naming. `START` and `END` are declared with `final` so they are constant. Should they still be lowercase because their parameters? I didn't make `heap` uppercase even though it's declared with `final` because it's an array. If a variable is an array (and isn't declared in the parameters) and is declared with `final` is the convention to still name it all in uppercase?

Comment: According to the Oracle style guide, `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` is only to be used for class constants. All other variable names should be `camelCase`. This includes method parameters, `final` or not.

Comment: @kidinme12 Look at Benjamin Kuykendall's comment above. By 'constants', I mean fields declared as `static final`.

Answer (score 5):

You code loops through the possible parents and checks the heap invariant for both children. This is a little messy: you have a special case for odd-number heaps, and you have two different conditions to check.

How about we loop through the possible children instead?

```java
private boolean isHeap(final int[] heap, final int start, final int end) {      
    for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
        if (heap[i] > heap[i/2]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```